# how to update a column having duplicates with sequential numbers using if statements in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

How to do numbering/sequencing for sets of same column values using if condition in sql server? For example:

```
Col1 Col2
Andy  1
Chad  1
Bill  1 
Andy  2
Bill  2
Bill  3
Chad  2
Bill  4
```

Comment: Why using *CURSOR* when you have some many easier way to generate the sequence

Comment: Using cursor is the homework for me

Comment: Seems you altered the question to not ask for a cursor based solution. Do you want one or not? Have you investigate cursors at all? Here is one example: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1599/sql-server-cursor-example/

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT Col1,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Col2
FROM yourTable
```